# Proababilities - passwords from 5 characters

Tags: probability

How many passwords with the length of 5 characters can be created if the characters don't repeat. (We use 26 characters).

How many password with the length of 5 characters can be created if the characters can repeat. (We use 26 characters).

For Q1 I think is $$A_{26}^{5}$$ but for Q2 I don't know. Can you help me, please?

I can say $$C_{26}^{5}$$ or $26^5$? What is the difference?

Comment: What is $A^5_{26}?$  Yet another notation for combinations-I presume $C^5_{26}$ is the number of combinations choosing $5$ from $26$.  But for Q2, it has to be greater than Q1-you have allowed new possibilities, and clearly order matters here.  Combinations can't be right.

Answer (score 1):

We use $C$ to get a number of different subsets from a set. In your example, we get a number of different 5-letter subsets from 26-letter set. Letters in these subsets can't repeat nor they can't be the same but in different order (subsets $AB$ and $BA$ from set $ABC$ will be counted as 1).

$A$ is the same as $C$, but it count $AB$ and $BA$ as 2 different subsets from my example, so it's correct for the first part of your question.

For the second part you should use $26^5$ instead of $C$.

Answer (score 0):

It's the number of 5 digit base-26 numbers.

Comment: *What* is the number of 5-digit base-26 numbers? There are two (related) questions here. Also, how did you get this, and how does it help?

Comment: Suppose you wanted all possible 5 digit passwords, with repetitions allowed.  There would be 100,000 of them, consisting of all 5 digit numbers (including 00000).  Shift gears for a second.  There are 10 one digit numbers.  There are 100 two digit numbers, 10^2, and so on.  Now in binary you only have 2 possible digits.  There are 2 one digit numbers and 2^2 two digit numbers and 2^3 three digit numbers.  In base 8 there would be 8^4 four digit base 8 numbers.  Your problem is as if there were 26 possible digits.  I hope this lead in helps.